# How do I approximate a multivariable polynomial equation using Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, approximation

I've been trying to experiment and test the extents to which a neural network works.

I was only able to make something with broad categorical variables function in an acceptable amount of time and in essence it was linear as each part of it could be reduced to linear function.

Eg conversion to polar coordinates given a constant angular measure just yields a real constant when you plug the angle into cos/sin when you convert back to cartesian. etc etc

would have been different if I was solving for the angle I think.

Point is now I'm trying something simple, I have a NN with 2 inputs (x and y) both real numbers that I plug into a polynomial function with 2 dependent variables.

It defines a 1024 neuron hidden layer, which I selected because someone claimed to be able to approximate sin(x) this way.

How long should it take to become accurate ? What activation functions should I use ? There don't really seem to be guidelines I can find to indicate how long until values start becoming less random.

Initially I started this and trained an lr/mom of 0.001/0.9.  Training in randomly introduced parameters on the domain of each variable of 0-100 normalizing the training data.

After somewhere around 40000 runs it began to closely resemble the slop of the plane of plotting the equation a 3d axis and then selecting 100 random points  via inferencing random parameters on the domain into it.

Around 50,000 training batches all the values plateaued back to a level elevated plane.  What happened here ?

Comment: Polynomial function has asymptotic that your neural net should match. So your output layer needs to reflect the asymptotes. It can’t be linear or sigmoid etc

Comment: Note also that, How long to train and how accurate would depend on the quality of the training data as well. In this case, a fine-grained synthetic data that covers "all the patterns".

Comment: I'm just randomly calculating the values of a function and training. You know just saying 'for the sake of argumemt  0<=x<=100 and 0<=y<=100

Comment: I don't expect it to work past these values, since I know the limitations of regression well enough.

Comment: Chapter 17 of this book has a lot on precisely this topic.  https://www.routledge.com/Understanding-Regression-Analysis-A-Conditional-Distribution-Approach/Westfall-Arias/p/book/9780367458522

Comment: @Aksakal can't be sigmoid :(.... there is a good point you just made as well.... what value would it even return when it hit an asymptote ? seems like with the current design I would be training around the asymptotes. wherever they may be, as i am using sigmoid as the final activation function atm...

Comment: @MehmetSüzen yayyy only 120.00 :) I am totally rolling in money right now lol

Comment: @Aksakal honestly in the domain I'm specifying I don't think there would be any asymptotes. I don't think there would be any period. This is not a 1/(x^2) sort of deal. Its a f(x)=x^2+y^2  sort of deal,  3 dimensions. and i'm only interested in a domain of [0,100]

Comment: If the donation is bounded then you don’t worry about asymptotes

Comment: @Aksakal wouldn't it always kind of have to be ? because of the nature of NNs ?

Comment: Not really. It depends on the problem.

Comment: @Aksakal well specifically to polynomial regression involving multiple input variables, I would think if you made it say 'project into infinity' this would cause an issue since an NN is a bunch of multipled sums lol